# Heredoc with powerline

Tags: bash, heredoc, powerline

When I try to use [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) with [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline), I get blank segments before each new line:
[image: heredoc in powerline]
How can I fix it so that it looks lsomething ike this:
[image: heredoc in powerline-shell]

Comment: Examine the value of `PS2`. Not a programming question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a theme for `continuation` (file `~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/continuation.json`) with the following content:

```
{
    "segments": {
        "left": [
            {
                "type": "string",
                "contents": ">",
                "highlight_groups": ["continuation"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's the result:
[image: fixed powerline]